# Convert Bitmap to single channel byte array with gray scale values in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to convert a bitmap with with ARGB_8888 format into a single channel
byte array that need to be consumed in a native part of the application.

I did some sanity checks using

```
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
 int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
 int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
 int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
 int alphaValue = Color.alpha(pixel);
```

And it seems that the format is actually RGBA and not ARGB.

I used the following code to achieve this task

```
public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bm) {
        // Create the buffer with the correct size
        int iBytes = bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight() ;
        byte[] res = new byte[iBytes];
        Bitmap.Config format = bm.getConfig();
        if (format == Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(iBytes*4);
            // Log.e("DBG", buffer.remaining()+""); -- Returns a correct number based on dimensions
            // Copy to buffer and then into byte array
            bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] arr = buffer.array();
            for(int i=0;i<iBytes;i++)
            {
                int A,R,G,B;
                R=(int)(arr[i*4+0]) & 0xff;
                G=(int)(arr[i*4+1]) & 0xff;
                B=(int)(arr[i*4+2]) & 0xff;
                //A=arr[i*4+3];
                byte r = (byte)(0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B) ;
                res[i] = r;
            }
        }
        if (format == Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(iBytes*2);
            // Log.e("DBG", buffer.remaining()+""); -- Returns a correct number based on dimensions
            // Copy to buffer and then into byte array
            bm.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] arr = buffer.array();
            for(int i=0;i<iBytes;i++)
            {
                float A,R,G,B;
                R = ((arr[i*2+0] & 0xF8) );
                G = ((arr[i*2+0] & 0x7) << 5) + ((arr[i*2+1] & 0xE0) >> 5);
                B = ((arr[i*2+1] & 0x1F) << 3 );
                byte r = (byte)(0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B) ;
                res[i] = r;
            }
        }
        // Log.e("DBG", buffer.remaining()+""); -- Returns 0
        return res;
    }
}
```

the byte array is being sent to a remote server for debugging reasons.
When i reconstruct the bitmap in the server I get the image all pixelated and with weird values in the gray level.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Any comment will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: At least a part of the problem may be that byte is signed (value range from -128 to 127)

Comment: This is why I do R=(int)(arr[i*4+0]) & 0xff; where R is of type int

Answer (score 0):

O.K , found the source of problems and found a solution which is different and less error prone.

1) pixelated dark image  was due to the fact that the input image was in RGB565 format , and recovering the RGB was messed up ... see the following native code I now use to see the difference:

```
> void MYJNI::ConvertRGBToGRAY(unsigned char in[], unsigned char
> out[],int w,int h,int type)
>     {
>       int sz = w*h;
>       char msg[300];
>       sprintf(msg,"width = %u height = %u sz = %u",w,h,sz);
>     #if defined(__ANDROID__) || defined(ANDROID)
>       __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"MOBLINK", msg);
>     #endif
>       if (type == 0) //RGBA
>       {
>           for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
>           {
>               float A,R,G,B;
>               R=in[i*4+0];
>               G=in[i*4+1];
>               B=in[i*4+2];
>               //A=arr[i*4+3];
>               unsigned char ir = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B;
>               out[i] = ir;
>           }
>       }
>       else if(type == 1) //RGB565
>       {
>           uint16_t *parr = (uint16_t*)in;
>           for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
>           {
>               float A,R,G,B;
>               R = ((parr[i] & 0xF800)>> 11) *8;
>               G = ((parr[i] & 0x07e0)>> 5) *4;
>               B = ((parr[i] & 0x001F)>> 0) *8;
>               
>               unsigned char ir = 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B;
>               out[i] = ir;
>           }
>       }
>     }
```

I use native function, because java based was way too slow.